# How to import module in typescript with "module" in "tsconfig" set to "es2022"?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I'm trying to import a class in typescript with the following lines of code:

```
import { Person } from "../files/class";
import { Chicken } from "./chicken";

console.log("helo");
const chick = new Chicken();
chick.cluck();

const person = new Person();
person.scream();
```

I need access to top-level await, so I sellected the following configuration:

```
"target": "ES2017" ,
"module": "ES2022",
"moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
```

As the result, I get this error:

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
warning:60
Uncaught SyntaxError C:\Users\Роман\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\learn_typescript\dist\src\index.js:1
import { Person } from "../files/class";
```

How can I resolve it?

If I set the "module" to "commonJS", it is working. However, in that case I don't gave access to top-level await, which is something I need

Comment: Did you read the warning?